# DB migrations, huge amount of data inserting

Tags: php, database

So, I writing DB migration using PHP framework X.

Migration updates structure of my old DB table.

I need to add many new data rows in this old table, for example, 10 000 rows.

A simple example of how my migration class looks:

```
<?php

  class Migration
  {
     public function up()
     {
     }

     public function down()
     {
     }
  }
```

I have 2 questions:

1. Should I write all my data inserting code in `up()` method?
2. If so should I keep all this inserting code in my version control system?

Comment: you have this data in sql file?

Comment: If you really want to use migrations, you could put the data itself to a better format (like JSON or CSV) and parse that data in your migration file

Comment: @KamilKiełczewski yes, i can export my data to MySQL files

Comment: @NicoHaase This will need for managing those files, keep them somewhere. I want to find better solution.

Comment: What do you mean by that? What exactly should be solved for a "better" solution?

Comment: @NicoHaase Better solution for me, in this case, is automation, I want to write the next version of my app, perform many tables changes, add some new data, remove old data, change tables structure. And when I deploy my code to production I want to run 1 command and not care about DB at all.

Comment: But the main question should be: why should there be tons of new data in a new version of an app? A migration is meant to change the structure of tables

Comment: And if you need to change lots of data, well just do it. What is the argument against holding all that data within the migration itself or in an external file that needs to be parsed?

Answer (score 4):

Essentially migration file is not for (big) data insertion (which also add big files to git repo...) but rather for db schema update - so is better to transfer data using some external tool (DB client)

Answer (score -1):

1. Write migration without data insertion.
2. Write seeder to insert data in the table.

Comment: Can you explain more what you mean about seeder?

Comment: Why should one use a database migration without inserting data?